# Firestore realtime query (SnapshotListener) stops getting updates, and all other Firestore queries won't get data

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Firestore database with my Android app.
After I updated Firebase libraries to the latest stable ones, and implemented the "firebase-crashlytics" lib instead of fabric, my Firestore real-time queries are not working as expected!
There is nothing in the logcat that indicates a problem with Firestore SDK or Firebase, just the Firestore query stops getting updates (or gets updated after few minutes).

I created a sample project to reproduce this issue/bug/error, i put it on this public github repository :
https://github.com/MahmoudiOussama/firestore-sample

This is my app gradle file
[image: My app Gradle file]

This is my project gradle file
[image: My project Gradle file]

Comment: If you noticed this in the last update, I think that you should better take this with to an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues) with the library so that they can check your specific case and help you (and if it is a bug on the library, they will be able to identify it and help you out.

Comment: Ok, thank you Luis Manuel.